# How to read List of Kotlin Pairs from application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, yaml

I am working on a Spring Boot project in Kotlin. I would like to read a list of `<String,Int>` pairs from application.yml file to a mutablelist. The type of the list is as follows.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "user-parameters")
class UserParameters {
    
    /**
     * Owners of the knapsacks and their capacity.
     */
    var knapsacks = mutableListOf<Pair<String, Int>>()
    
    init {
      ...
    }
}
```

In the application.yml file, I tried to use the following configuration.

```
...
user-parameters:
  knapsacks:
   - "[James]": 102
   - "[Mary]": 185
```

However, this fails with the following error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target [Bindable@3a7b2e2 type = java.util.List<kotlin.Pair<java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer>>, value = 'provided', annotations = array<Annotation>[[empty]]] failed:

    Property: user-parameters.knapsacks[0][James]
    Value: 102
    Origin: class path resource [application.yml] - 28:17
    Reason: The elements [user-parameters.knapsacks[0][James],user-parameters.knapsacks[1][Mary]] were left unbound.
    Property: user-parameters.knapsacks[1][Mary]
    Value: 185
    Origin: class path resource [application.yml] - 29:16
    Reason: The elements [user-parameters.knapsacks[0][James],user-parameters.knapsacks[1][Mary]] were left unbound.

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

The code works if I change the type to `Map<String, Int>` but I need `Pair<String, Int>` due to implementation details.

I have also tried the following annotations but to no avail.

```
...
user-parameters:
  knapsacks:
   - "[James]": 102
     "[Mary]": 185
```

```
...
user-parameters:
  knapsacks:
   "[James]": 102
   "[Mary]": 185
```

```
...
user-parameters:
  knapsacks:
   - { "[James]": 102 }
   - { "[Mary]": 185 }
```

How can I achieve reading pairs of `String,Int` to a mutable list from application.yml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know Spring Boot does not support `Pair` of the `kotlin-stdlib` out-of-the-box.

Spring cannot know how to parse arbitrary classes in arbitrary ways. Spring does support classes following Bean conventions however.

Thus, there are at least three solutions to your problem:

1. Simply parse as `Map` as outlined in the question and convert your `Map<String, Int>` to a `List<Pair<String, Int>>`, e.g. by calling `map.toList()`, see the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-list.html).

You may provide a custom getter for the list.

```kotlin
val knapsacksList: List<Pair<String, Int>>
   get() { knapsacks.toList() }
```

2. Adjust your `application.yml` to conform to the form of `Pair`. A `Pair` is a simple data class having two values being `first` and `second`. If you provide these in the .yml-file, Spring can parse them accordingly.

Something along the lines of the following may work.

```
...
user-parameters:
  knapsacks:
   - first: "James"
     second: 102"
   - first: "Mary"
     second: 185
```

3. Provide a custom `Converter` for your use case. There are resources online on how to achieve this, for example from [baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-type-conversions).

Comment: Quick tip on posting paragraphs and code blocks inside Markdown list items - if you indent material here once it becomes an indented paragraph, and if you indent twice it becomes a code block. Thus, although the formatting here is fine, you can indent material in lists completely if you wish.